# SQL for selectively deleting duplicate records based on expiry dates

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a MariaDB table as follows:

| userid | username | email | expirydate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | jackd | jackd@example.com | 2018-10-09 |
| 2 | jillf | jillf@example.com | 2022-12-19 |
| 3 | aaron | aaron@someone.com | 2022-09-29 |
| 4 | aaron1 | aaron@someone.com | 2021-12-19 |
| 5 | jackd2 | jackd@example.com | 2017-11-03 |
| 6 | jackd3 | jackd@example.com | 2019-10-09 |
| 7 | simd | simd@somewhere.com | 2023-03-13 |
| 8 | simdb | simd@somewhere.com | 2024-10-09 |

It allows users to login using their username, which is unique. The
other columns are not unique. Specifically, a user can have multiple
accounts by using different usernames, but each account can have the
same email address. Most users only have one username.

We are moving to a login system based on email rather than username
meaning that email now needs to be unique and we need to clean up the
table as we have duplicate emails. Associating a user with an email
means that users can have some accounts that are not expired, some
that are expired and any combination of these two properties. For
example, user with email jackd@example.com has three accounts which
are all expired whereas aaron@someone.com has one expired account and
one active account. simd@somewhere.com has two accounts that are both
active. Other combinations of expired and active are possible.

I would like to do the following:

- Keep all duplicate email rows where all expiry dates are in the future (e.g., keep both rows for simd@somewhere.com).
- Where emails are associated with a mixture of expired and active rows, delete only the rows that have expired (e.g., keep the first row
  and delete the second row for arron@someone.com).
- Where emails are associated with all rows being expired, keep the latest (based on expiry date) row and delete the rest (e.g., keep the
  last row and delete the first two for jackd@example.com).
- Only duplicate email rows should be targeted.

The end table would look like this:

| userid | username | email | expirydate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | jillf | jillf@example.com | 2022-12-19 |
| 3 | aaron | aaron@someone.com | 2022-09-29 |
| 6 | jackd3 | jackd@example.com | 2019-10-09 |
| 7 | simd | simd@somewhere.com | 2023-03-13 |
| 8 | simdb | simd@somewhere.com | 2024-10-09 |

I have tried everything I can think of, but I'm constantly failing.
Any help would be very much appreciated. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the results you want by using a CTE to determine ordering of expiry dates for each user, and figuring out if that user has any unexpired accounts (taking advantage of the fact that the `MIN` of logical values is equivalent to `AND`). Then you select rows from that CTE where either the account has not expired, or - if the email has only expired accounts - the account has the latest expiry date:

```sql
WITH rns AS (
  SELECT *, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY email ORDER BY expirydate DESC) AS rn,
         MIN(expirydate < CURDATE()) OVER (PARTITION BY email) AS allexpired
  FROM users
)
SELECT userid, username, email, expirydate
FROM rns
WHERE expirydate >= CURDATE()
   OR allexpired AND rn = 1
ORDER BY userid
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
userid  username    email               expirydate
2       jillf       jillf@example.com   2022-12-19
3       aaron       aaron@someone.com   2022-09-29
6       jackd3      jackd@example.com   2019-10-09
7       simd        simd@somewhere.com  2023-03-13
8       simdb       simd@somewhere.com  2024-10-09
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=243a78378cb1993890b9904de3b4f279)

To delete the unwanted records from your table, you can use a `DELETE` with the CTE, as long as you are running MariaDB 10.4 or later (there is a bug which prevents it working in MariaDB 10.3 and earlier).

```sql
DELETE users FROM users
JOIN (
  WITH rns AS (
    SELECT *, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY email ORDER BY expirydate DESC) AS rn,
           MIN(expirydate < CURDATE()) OVER (PARTITION BY email) AS allexpired
    FROM users
  )
  SELECT userid
  FROM rns
  WHERE expirydate < CURDATE() AND (NOT allexpired OR rn > 1)
) del
WHERE users.userid = del.userid
```

For MariaDB 10.3 and earlier, the simplest workaround is to create a new table with the desired rows, drop the old table and then rename the new table to the old. This would be the `CREATE TABLE` command:

```sql
CREATE TABLE users2 (
  `userid` INTEGER,
  `username` VARCHAR(6),
  `email` VARCHAR(18),
  `expirydate` DATE
) AS
WITH rns AS (
  SELECT *, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY email ORDER BY expirydate DESC) AS rn,
         MIN(expirydate < CURDATE()) OVER (PARTITION BY email) AS allexpired
  FROM users
)
SELECT userid, username, email, expirydate
FROM rns
WHERE expirydate >= CURDATE()
   OR allexpired AND rn = 1
ORDER BY userid
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=6ef0f75177308ec5b610a76ec077d810)

Comment: Thank you Nick. I have been breaking down each part of your answer to see how it works and it's been very interesting. Your solution leaves me with the correct rows, but I am looking to see how to delete those rows that have been correctly excluded using your solution. I have been unable to do so. I have been trying to delete these unwanted rows by using a delete statement with a NOT IN part wrapped around your solution, but without success. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: @Ads apologies - I missed the "deleting" part of the title to the question. I've updated my answer to include the way to do this with MariaDB 10.4 and above. If you're not using that recent a version, your options are really limited to creating a new table with the selected rows and then dropping the old and renaming the new.

Comment: thank you. That worked perfectly! I have accepted your answer.